# Is std::isspace the opposite of std::isgraph in C++ (locale versions)

Tags: c++, locale, whitespace, isspace

Is std::isspace the opposite of std::isgraph in C++ (locale versions)? That is, is the following true?

```
char c = getCharFromSomewhere();
std::locale loc = getLocaleFromSomewhere();
std::isspace(c, loc) != std::isgraph(c, loc)
```

They seem to be true when I test, but I can't be certain this is true in all locales.

Comment: I would say no.  There are control characters, e.g. `'\a'`, which are not spaces and not graphic.  See [`std::isgraph`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isgraph), especially the chart at the bottom.

Comment: `graph` is defined as `alnum | punct`, but there is also `cntrl` and `print` which are not included in it.